# How to get a UIButton's UIControlTouchDragInside and UIControlTouchDragOutside threshold to be the frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicontrol

It appears that a UIButton's [UIControlEventTouchDragInside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragInside) and [UIControlEventTouchDragOutside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragOutside) threshold is outside the frame of the button by some unknown amount.  This distance seems to be about the size of a finger width.  Is there some way to get this threshold to be the actual frame/bounds without this finger width buffer?

This has not been an issue on the iPad but on the iPhone and smaller real estate it is causing my custom control work sporadically.

Thanks

Comment: well, `CGSize treshold = CGSizeMake(widthOfYourFingerInPixels, widthOfYourFingerInPixels);`

Comment: The DragInsideEvent is firing all the way outside of the button frame by some distance.  I would expect that that DragInsideEvent would fire until it reaches the edge of the button frame.  Then the DragOutsideEvent would fire.  This is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I am doing the following.

I have altered my [UIControlEventTouchUpInside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchUpInside) and [UIControlEventTouchUpOutside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)'s handlers.

```
-(IBAction)myButtonsUpInside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
```

and

```
-(IBAction)myButtonsUpOutside:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
```

to to first check if the event should be handled as a different button. With something like this:

```
NSArray* theTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
UITouch* touch = [theTouches objectAtIndex:0];
if([btnMyOtherButton pointInside:[touch locationInView:btnMyOtherButton] withEvent:event])
     //Call myOtherButton's action.
//Otherwise do this button's action.
```

You can also do the same thing with [UIControlEventTouchDragInside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragInside) and [UIControlEventTouchDragOutside](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragOutside) handlers to do something similar.  I only needed action to happen on the touch up event.

Still would like to know if anyone has any other solution to rid themselves of this weird buffer.